# htaccess remove country variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Sorry, but I couldn't find any help for my problem. Hoping you guys can help.

I have the url:

```
http://example.com/country-prefix/.well-known/other-part
```

I would like to turn that into just:

```
http://example.com/.well-known/other-part
```

so remove country-prefix whatever it is, for example:

```
http://example.com/pl/.well-known/other-part =>  http://example.com/.well-known/other-part

http://example.com/us/.well-known/other-part =>  http://example.com/.well-known/other-part
```

only if /.well-known/ in url

I know it can be done like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.well-known/
RewriteRule ^/?(pl|eu)/(.*)$ $2
```

but is it possible to not include all languages prefix in RewriteRule (so it works for all languages), like for example above will work for:

```
http://example.com/pl/.well-known/other-part
```

but not for

```
http://example.com/us/.well-known/other-part
```

Comment: Just use `[^/]+`? It's just regex. You can omit `/?` at the start if this is in a .htaccess file, because paths are guaranteed to not start with that in a .htaccess file (it filters out the current path and appends it again later).

Comment: perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to:Sumurai8

if someone will need it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /.well-known/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]+/(.*)$ $1
```